# Rules for doctypes

Tags: html

After going through a lot of articles and this post, i know Why doctypes are used for and also about the different modes triggered by the browser like standards, quirks etc.

I downloaded the a strict doctype from this url - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd but couldn't understand a thing of what is written inside it.

My question is, if i want to write a page with html and css which is going to have a doctype that will trigger standards mode, where can i get a clear and simple to understand list of all the rules(for instance, elements and attributes that i should avoid) that my html and css code should adhere to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specification itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/ The DTD itself is harder to read because it's written in a spec language, [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), and not plain English. Backus-Naur is worth learning if you truly want to be sure of the exact meaning of the spec.

It's OK to move on to the newer version of the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` as it sets all browsers to standards mode and also makes the validator aware should you start using the new HTML5 elements. (Do not think of it as a "HTML5 doctype".)

There isn't anything you should avoid if it's in the spec except those marked, there, as "deprecated". If you want to future proof yourself, here is the [list of differences with HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/).

For that matter, here is the [HTML5 "living standard"](http://developers.whatwg.org/).